# Java SOAP class not present

Tags: java, soap

What should occur when a Java class is not present? We have a SOAP setup with a client and a server. We have the following code:

```
try{

new myClass()
} catch (Exception e){}
```

And in myClass, there is the other object created "classNotReallyPresent" which is the one that is located in a .jar that we never put on the server, which is why we get errors. However we're surprised that the catch block didn't do anything, and no messages get printed on our server logs.. so I ask, what is the expected behavior in this kind of scenario where a class (myClass) cannot be instantiated because of an member object/variable it is constructing (classNotReallyPresent) that is missing a .class file?

Answer (score 1):

You are not printing the error in your `catch` clause. The most simple way of printing it is to use the following code:

```
try{
    new myClass();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Besides this, it is not good to catch `Exception`, better only catch `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: No, that isn't it. The code I posted was an example, not the actual code. The Exception never gets caught, that was the point of the example.